# Retrieve data from an Eventlet GreenPile object, possibly iterator related

Tags: python, iterator, eventlet

I am currently modifying a simple monitoring script I made some time ago that basically :

Build a list of dictionaries containing, amongst other things

- A website URL
- The time it took to respond (set as None by default)
- The data it sent back (set as None by default)

Query (GET) each URL from the list and fill the 'time' and 'data' fields with the relevant data.

Store the results in a database.

The script used to work fine, but as the list of URLS to monitor grew the time it takes to complete all the queries has become way too long for me.

My solution is to modify the script to fetch the URLs in a concurrent way. To do that I chose to use [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/), since [this example](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#web-crawler) from the documentation does almost exactly what I want.

The catch is that since my list of URLs contains dictionaries I can't use `pool.imap()` to iterate through my list. (As far as I know)

The Eventlet documentation has another similar example* that uses a GreenPile object to spawn jobs, it seems I can use that to launch my URL fetching function, but I can't seem to be able to retrieve the result of this thread.

Here is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2


urls = [{'url': 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif', 'data': None},
{'url': 'http://www.google.com', 'data': None}]


def fetch(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()


pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
pile = eventlet.GreenPile(pool)


for url in urls:
    pile.spawn(fetch, url['url']) #can I get the return of the function here?

#or
for url in urls:
    url['data'] = ??? #How do I get my data back?

#Eventlet's documentation way
data = "\n".join(pile)
```

As far as I understand `pile` is an iterable so I can iterate through it but I can't access its content via an index, is this correct?

So, how (is it possible?) can I directly fill my `urls` list? Another solution could be build one "flat" list of urls, another list containing the url, resp time and data and use `pool.imap()` on the first list and fill the second one with that, but I'd rather keep my list of dictionaries.

*I can't post more than 3 links with this account, please see the "Design patterns - Dispatch patterns" page from the eventlet documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `GreenPile` but you need to return something from your `fetch` so you  have more than just the response. I modified the example so `fetch` returns a tuple that is the url and the response body.

The `urls` variable is now a dict of urls(string) to data (None or string). Iterating over a `GreenPile` continues until there are no more tasks. Iterating should be done in the same thread that calls `spawn`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2


#Change to map urls to the data found at them
urls = {'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif': None,
'http://www.google.com' :None}


def fetch(url):
    #return the url and the response
    return (url, urllib2.urlopen(url).read())


pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
pile = eventlet.GreenPile(pool)


for url in urls.iterkeys():
    pile.spawn(fetch, url) #can I get the return of the function here? - No

for url,response in pile:
    #stick it back into the dict
    urls[url] = response

for k,v in urls.iteritems():
    print '%s - %d bytes' % (k,len(v))
```